# Directory Location is not writable

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I had installed oracle database 11g XE then started to create database by using DBCA but at step 6 (Database configuration assistant) of 12 it is saying "Directory location `D:\app\user\oradata\test` is not writable.

I tried so many times but its always the same.How can I solve this problem?

This dialog is appearing

[image: This dialog is appearing]

Comment: perhaps you do not have the permission to write

Answer (score 0):

You can stop doing what you are doing as it won't work.

11g **Express Edition** (XE) database is installed during (initial) installation process. As XE allows only one instance, you can't create another database anyway so - stop trying.

If you want to practice such things (which is perfectly OK), switch to e.g. **Standard Edition**. It is dowloadable (for free, for education purposes) from the Oracle Technology Network.